Automation Error Runtime Error Invalid Syntax
I am trying to automate some of the SAP process. While doing the automation, I am able to record and see the SAP GUI script as well.
While trying to execute the VB script, earlier it used to have worked on my laptop itself but now from past few days I am getting error as

Runtime error -2147221020 (800401e4) Automation error
Invalid Syntax

After debugging, I came to know that error has been thrown at this point:
Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")

My SAP LOGON window is already in open but seems like GetObject is Nothing or empty, GetObject is not returning the values or null.
I had searched through many articles and blogs but I cannot find any solutions related to this particular issue.
Can someone help me with any inputs here how to solve this error ?

Did you check the references, to see if SAPGUI is present ? Does the code compile ?

@iDevlop yes references are there and code is compiling

You say "SAP LOGON [...] open", but did you open an SAP GUI session before running the script? (i.e. after entering SAP user/password)

@SandraRossi, it is an SSO login and it will be already running at Easy Access for ****** Menu before I execute the VB script
